# How to find all unselected checkboxes?

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

In jQuery, how does one go about finding all the 'unchecked' checked boxes.

```
$(':checkbox:checked');
```

appears to be me all checked boxes, but what I need is all non-checked boxes.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You use the [`:not`](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/not#selector) selector, like so:

```
$('input:checkbox:not(:checked)');
```

Or the [`.not`](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/not#expr) function, like so:

```
$('input:checkbox').not(':checked');
```

Also note that you should always put `input` before filters like `:radio` and `:checkbox`, as without that the selector are evaluated as `*:checkbox` which is a *really slow* selector.

Comment: Thank you Paolo.  I had actually played around with the 'not', but I didn't manage to get the ":" in the right place or something.  In any case, works now. Thanks.  Thanks for guide on *: versus input:

Answer (score 1):

A solution without special jQuery selectors, using the [*attribute selector* <sup>[docs]</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) and [`.filter()` <sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').filter(function() {
    return !this.checked;
});
```