# Find all unchecked checkboxes in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, input, checkbox

I have a list of checkboxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="answer" id="id_1' value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="answer" id="id_2' value="2" />
...
<input type="checkbox" name="answer" id="id_n' value="n" />
```

I can collect all the values of checked checkboxes; my question is how can get all the values of unchecked checkboxes? I tried:

```
$("input:unchecked").val();
```

to get an unchecked checkbox's value, but I got:

> Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unchecked.

Can anybody shed a light on this issue?
Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: Find All Unselected Checkboxes, How To](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093350/jquery-find-all-unselected-checkboxes-how-to)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find all unselected checkboxes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093350/how-to-find-all-unselected-checkboxes)

Comment: @FelixKling This is clearly an exact duplicate. Please swing your jquery hammer.

Answer (score 508, accepted):

As the error message states, jQuery does not include a `:unchecked` selector.
Instead, you need to invert the `:checked` selector:

```
$("input:checkbox:not(:checked)")
```

Comment: And using input[type=checkbox] is fastest.

Answer (score 37):

`$("input:checkbox:not(:checked)")` Will get you the unchecked boxes.

Answer (score 17):

Also it can be achieved with pure js in such a way:

```
var matches = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)');
```

Answer (score 10):

You can do so by extending jQuerys functionality. This will shorten the amount of text you have to write for the selector.

```
$.extend($.expr[':'], {
        unchecked: function (obj) {
            return ((obj.type == 'checkbox' || obj.type == 'radio') && !$(obj).is(':checked'));
        }
    }
);
```

You can then use `$("input:unchecked")` to get all checkboxes and radio buttons that are checked.

Answer (score 4):

You can use like this :

```
$(":checkbox:not(:checked)")
```

Comment: Why repeat the guidance already provided years earlier?  Furthermore, please never post code-only snippets on SO.  All answers should be explained.

Answer (score 4):

To select by `class`, you can do this:

```
$("input.className:checkbox:not(:checked)")
```

Comment: The question asked does not have a `class` attribute.  This is an unnecessary answer since the suggestion of `:checkbox:not(:checked)` was given **YEARS** earlier.

Answer (score 3):

```
$("input[type='checkbox']:not(:checked):not('\#chkAll\')").map(function () { 
   var a = ""; 
   if (this.name != "chkAll") { 
      a = this.name + "|off"; 
   } 
   return a; 
}).get().join();
```

This will retrieve all unchecked checkboxes and exclude the "chkAll" checkbox that I use to check|uncheck all checkboxes.  Since I want to know what value I'm passing to the database I set these to off, since the checkboxes give me a value of on.

```
//looking for unchecked checkboxes, but don’t include the checkbox all that checks or unchecks all checkboxes
//.map - Pass each element in the current matched set through a function, producing a new jQuery object containing the return values.

//.get - Retrieve the DOM elements matched by the jQuery object.
//.join - (javascript) joins the elements of an array into a string, and returns the string.The elements will be separated by a specified separator. The default separator is comma (,).
```

Comment: You shouldn't be including something in your answer that is completely irrelevant for the OP. He doesn't use a `chkAll` box so what's the point of mentioning it.

Answer (score -1):

```
$(".clscss-row").each(function () {
if ($(this).find(".po-checkbox").not(":checked")) {
               // enter your code here
            } });
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please add an explanation to your code, so other users (for whom this might be what they're looking for) know what your code does.