# Convert :unchecked to prop('checked',false)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery version 1.8.0 and I'm getting error message as "Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unchecked"

jQuery changed unchecked to prop('checked',false) .I tried changing my code but, its not working.

```
 if($('input[name='+family+']:unchecked').length){
     }
```

I replaced this to

```
if($('input[name='+family+']).prop('checked',false).length){
 }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8465821/find-all-unchecked-checkbox-in-jquery

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `:not` selector with `:checked`:

```
if($('input[name='+family+']:not(:checked)').length){
   //do something..
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick

```
var uncheckedElems = $('input[name='+family+']')
.filter(function(){ 
    return !$(this).prop('checked')
});

if(uncheckedElems .length > 0)
{
 //Code here
}
```