# How to show Ajax response in a PHP while loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have the following input box in PHP while loop:

```
echo '<ul>';
  while ( $data = $supplier->result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $sid          =  (int) $data['sid'];
    $supplierName = output($data['supplierName']);
    $vid          = output($data['vid']);

    echo "
    <li>
      <input type='checkbox' name='sid[]' data-sid='$sid' value='{$sid}|$vid' class='supplierClass'> $supplierName
      <div class='allVehicle'></div>
    </li>
    ";  
  }
echo '</ul>';
```

Now when I click on a checkbox it's calling another PHP page using jQuery/Ajax, but the result is not showing.

jQuery/Ajax Code:

```
$('.supplierClass').change(function() {    
   var sids = [];
   $('.supplierClass:checked').each(function(i,v) {
       sids.push($(v).val());
    });
    $.ajax({
      url         :   'process/get-vehicle.php',
      type        :   'POST',
      dataType    :   'html',
      data        :   {
        sid   :  sids,
      },
      beforeSend  :   function () {
          $(this).next('.allVehicle').html('Please wait...');
      },
      success     :   function ( result ) {
          $(this).next('.allVehicle').html(result);
      }
   });  
});
```

I think the problem is on this line but not sure.

```
beforeSend  :   function () {
    $(this).next('.allVehicle').html('Please wait...');
},
success     :   function ( result ) {
    $(this).next('.allVehicle').html(result);
}
```

Comment: You want do `$('.supplierClass').change(function() {    
   var sids = [];var that = this;…`. Or `('.supplierClass:checked').each(function(i,v) {
       sids.push($(v).val());var that = this`. And `$(that).next('.allVehicle').html(result);`.  Depending on which `this` you mean. The `this` you use is the one from the `$.ajax()` `function`.

Comment: Open developers console. WHat do you see there?

Comment: @u_mulder no output is showing.

Comment: @AjAX. don't get you :(

Comment: Which `this` do you mean?

Comment: @AjAX.SUPPPPER :) But why I need to assign this to that?

Comment: You want to cache it. Because at the place you are using it, it is — not — the `value` you think it is. It is `window`.

Comment: @AjAX. Well, it's working but having some issue. When I click on multiple checkboxes it's showing the data but when I uncheck any checkbox then the data is still showing to the corresponding div. it's should not be.

Comment: You want to do it manually. [Like `$('li input:not(:checked)').next().empty()`.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8465833/2569323)

Comment: where should I add this line?

Comment: Try it in the `change()` `function`. And this is just an example. To lead you the way.

Answer (score 0):

Change it like that, if works!

```
beforeSend  :   function () {
  $('.allVehicle').next().html('Please wait...');
},
success     :   function ( result ) {
  $('.allVehicle').next().html(result);
 //$('.allVehicle').next().text(result); if not workout as html then test it by passing text in it.
}
```

And if not done then https://api.jquery.com/next/ have a visit here.